# Multiple losses in Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

In my simple Variational Autoencoder code, I want to see both reconstruction and KL divergance loss values when the model is running. I used the [Example of VAE on MNIST dataset using MLP](https://keras.io/examples/variational_autoencoder/) in Keras documentation page, and modified the loss part as below:

```
reconstruction_loss = original_dim*binary_crossentropy(inputs,outputs)                                              
kl_loss = -0.5*K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)



losses = {  'recon_loss': reconstruction_loss,
             'latent_loss': kl_loss,
             'total_loss': vae_loss,}


vae.add_loss(losses)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
history = vae.fit(x_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,
                validation_data=(x_test, None))
```

But when I run the model, the **Compile** command returns this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-b668ab0f8437> in <module>
----> 1 vae.compile(optimizer='adam')
      2 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    349                     total_loss += loss_weight * output_loss
    350             if total_loss is None:
--> 351                 if not self.losses:
    352                     raise ValueError('The model cannot be compiled '
    353                                      'because it has no loss to optimize.')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in losses(self)
    423 
    424         unique_tensors = list(
--> 425             set(x for x in losses if not isinstance(x, (float, int))))
    426         non_tensors = [x for x in losses if isinstance(x, (float, int))]
    427         return unique_tensors + non_tensors

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I have seen some other questions about ***TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'***, but I couldn't solve my problem. Are there any idea to adopt the Compile command in Keras and work with multiple losses?

Comment: Do you by chance have links to those other questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the loss functions and used the *metrics* in compile finction.

```
def recon_loss(inputs,outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = original_dim*binary_crossentropy(inputs,outputs)                                              
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss)

def latent_loss(inputs,outputs):
    kl_loss =  -0.5*K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)    
    return K.mean(kl_loss)

def total_loss(inputs,outputs):
    reconstruction_loss = original_dim*binary_crossentropy(inputs,outputs)                                              
    kl_loss =  -0.5*K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)   
    return K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=total_loss,metrics=[recon_loss, latent_loss])
```

Now, the model returns reconstruction, latent and total losses for both training and validation data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the type of each loss in your losses dictionary.

```
print (type(losses['recon_loss']))
```

Comment: For all losses, the type is:.   <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

Comment: The error above says that losses must be instance of int or float.

Comment: The reason that I changed the original definition of the loss is that I need both parts of the vae_loss. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. Just to resolve the above error, only pass a single loss to your model